# IPhone app In app purchase giveaway

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I have an application that my client wants to give away to customers for free.

To get the full functionality, the customers would have to fill in a code.

Other customers will need to do an In App Purchase to get the full functionality.

Is this allowed by Apple or will I bump into app store restrictions.

Tried to find it, but haven't found a decent answer.
Anyone tried it before ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Please see this other SO answer:
[Redeem codes for inapp purchase items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606266/redeem-codes-for-inapp-purchase-items)

I dont think it is possible to do what you want. Either everyone has to enter a code, or everyone has to do an in-app purchase.

You could also have both of these options available inside the app, but that may seem messy and informal for customers

Answer (score 0):

I would say you could ask the user for a login (email + password). You could then connect to a server of yours and check the credentials. If the server knows this user because you host a list of all the users allowed to use the premium options for free, you could unlock your premium features. Otherwise, you ask Apple for the In App Purchase precedure.